# Is there historical evidence that Emperor Ashoka converted to Buddhism?

Tags: india, buddhism

As far as I know, the only evidence having claim over the fact about Ashoka's conversion to Buddhism is the [Ashokavadana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashokavadana), a work of the Buddhists themselves. Nor is this fact verifiable by Ashoka's Edicts or Pillars.

Do we have any independent evidence (documentary or otherwise), about Ashoka's conversion to Buddhism? Maybe through the writings of any of the Greek Historians like Megasthenes or somebody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dipavamsa VI 18](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=K1lCQT_-k6MC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA45&focus=viewport&vq=50&dq=dipavamsa+VI+18&output=html_text) states (see page 43 in Oldenburg's work)

> *Asoko rajjam kâresi Pàțaliputte prurruttame,*
>
> *Abhisitto tîņi vassâni pasanno buddhasàsane*

Which roughly translates to,

**Ashoka ruled in Pataliputra, best of towns,
Three years after his coronation, he converted to Budhhism**

So, yes there is a source.

Comment: Three years after coronation? And what about all the stories that after the Kalinga war he felt a lot of remorse and because of that he converted. Kalinga war was much later than 3 years after coronation (10 years if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Prahalad Yeri " Kalinga war was much later than 3 years after coronation (10 years if I remember correctly)." Were you there in Ashoka's time? :) History which we see today, are speculations deduced from various tangible sources. And Dipavamsa is one of the sources contributing in deduction

Comment: @Rohit "Were you there in Ashoka's time?". That does not fit into History Stack Exchange. History is about not being there. So try to answer the question directly.

Comment: @Rajib oh come on :) some light hearted rhetoricals don't hurt anyone

Comment: OP asked a pertinent question. Please answer that.

Comment: @Rajib do you not find my answer satisfactory?

Comment: Any hagiography is questionable. But the greater problem in your answer is the mismatched chronology as pointed out by OP.

Comment: Did i not say on that?

Comment: Chronology does not descend from heavens right? People conclude that this must have happened at this and this time, because this and this points to so.

Comment: I think you have not understood the context. You have not added any caveat about timelines that I can see. Chronology IS fixed based on references. Move to chat?

Comment: @Rajib sure, but i have little idea how chat works. Lead me on pal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21736/discussion-between-rajib-and-rohit).

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. The OP asked if there exist any historical evidence of the conversion other than the one listed. Rohit answered the question with what looks to me like independent evidence. Asked and answered and very well done at that (sourced and all.)

Comment: @CGCampbell The OP mentions that the evidence obtained is from Buddhists themselves, and asks for an independent source, meaning non-religious. The book in question is undoubtedly a religious book. The preamble goes: "Listen! I shall relate the chronicle of the Buddha's visits to the island, the arrival of the Tooth Relic and the Bodhi tree, the advent of the Buddha's doctrine, the rise of the teachers, the spread of Buddhism in the island and the coming of Vijaya the Chief of Men."

Comment: @CGCampbell [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipavamsa) will clearly show that it is a Buddhist book. Any religious book makes great claims about the prophet, the patrons, kings and so on, that is the nature of creating religious narrative.