# Was religion in India a matter of choice for people during Mauryan empire?

Tags: india, religion, ancient-india

The three most important kings of the Mauryan empire were followers of different religions, though there are disputes since there is not enough evidence to support the claims about Chandragupta & Bindusar's religion in the later phases of their life.

Chandragupta Maurya converted to Jainism, though disputed but there are claims that he converted to Jain monk in the last days of his life

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandragupta_Maurya#Succession,_renunciation,_and_death_(Sallekhana))

> Chandragupta lived as an ascetic at Shravanabelagola for several years before fasting to death as per the Jain practice of sallekhana, according to the Digambara legend

Bindusara was follower of Ajivika religion

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindusara#Religion)

> Based on these legends, scholars such as A. L. Basham conclude that Bindusara patronized the Ajivikas.

and Ashoka was the converted to Buddhism after 3 years of his coronation as stated in this [History SE answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20744/is-there-historical-evidence-that-emperor-ashoka-converted-to-buddhism)

Though there are disputes still none of the resources states that any one of them were following a faith because their family or their father did so, it was with their will they were choosing their faiths, it was as if they were given the option to study all the religions and then embrace one of them.

Does this suggest Indian society during Mauryan times was very flexible for religions, were people free to change their faiths rather than going on following the same in most of the cases as their forefathers have been following?

Comment: None of the evidence would lead me to believe that "Indian society during Mauryan times was very flexible for religions,"; we have three anecdotes that suggest that rulers could convert, but rulers in every society have privileges that ordinary citizens do not.